# MS Access 2007: Organizing a metrics database

Tags: ms-access

Apologies in advance as I'm pretty inexperienced with Access, mySQL, etc.  I'm trying to learn :)

I could use some general advice that (I believe) won't require me diving into the weeds with pasting all of my code here, but we'll see.

I'm trying to develop a database for tracking and reporting metrics.  The metrics are derived from two tables: Volume and Dissemination.  They have mostly similar fields, the important ones being:

**Dissemination:** DisseminationID, Date

**Volume:** VolumeID, Date, Performance Measure, Type of Data

The end goal is to create a report (or reports if necessary) that are based on two totals, **by quarter**:

**TotalA:** Count of records in Dissemination + Count of certain records where performance measure is "data sharing" and type of data is not "xyz" in Volume

**TotalB:** Count of certain records in Volume.

Now the way I've approached this up to this point was to:

1) Create separate Count(*) queries for:

- Dissemination by quarter (qryD_Q1, Q2, etc)
- Dissemination total (qryDTotal)
- Volume by quarter where performance measure = data sharing, type of data is not xyz (qryShareTotal)
- Volume total according to the same criteria (qry_Share_Q1, Q2, etc)

2) Create union queries to calculate TotalA, using the following code:

```
> SELECT Sum([SQ].[SubTotal]) AS TotalA
  FROM (SELECT Sum(DTotal) AS SubTotal
    FROM qryDTotal
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Sum (ShareTotal)
    FROM qryShareTotal
    AS SQ;
```

3) Repeat #2 using corresponding queries for each quarter.

4) Create either select or make table queries combining the data from each so you have:

### TblTotalA

qryTotalA_Q1, qry_TotalA_Q2, qry_TotalA_Q3, qry_TotalA_Q4, qry_TotalA_Total

### TblTotalB

qryD_Q1, qryD_Q2, qryD_Q3, qryD_Q4, qryDTotal

My specific questions are:

1. Is there a much more efficient/streamlined way to do this that I missed, up to this point?
2. If I want to combine TblTotalA and TblTotalB into a single report, how could I go about it? Using the report wizard requires me to relate the tables, and I'm not sure how I'd relate them, unless I did it by quarter(?)

Thanks in advance.  With this database I'm expecting there will be a lot of this kind of thing so this will be huge as I continue to learn.

Edit: I'm guessing the simplest solution, assuming my queries stay the same, is to use subreports to capture results from both the queries..